# denydatawriter does not work in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, security

I have a couple of admin roles in a SQL Server 2012.

[image]

To prevent myself from changing data in one database, I added my login as a member of denydatawriter role to that database.

It seems does not work, still able to insert

[image]

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're also a member of sysadmin, all security checks are skipped.

Comment: thanks, so what is the good way to restrain DML only in one database, while keeping the sysadmin role on server?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, except for changing the database to read only?

Comment: What if you used `EXECUTE AS` to switch context in that DB to a more restricted user? Or, even have a more restricted login that you use when you're going to be working in that DB?

Comment: It's not exactly what you're looking for but I use a SQL login when I'm not strictly doing DBA work, and my windows login when I am. low-tech, but it's proven useful.